# Why is 'undefined' appearing in my webpage when it is not in the HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

When I load my webpage up, the word "undefined" appears in a `<ul>` that is then modified with javascript and `.innerHTML` after the page is loaded up.

This is how the HTML appears:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        "undefined
                    "
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If there are no `<li>`'s, then it just appears as so:

```
<div>
    <ul>undefined</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript function that seems to be causing it. The data parameter is the data from the database.

```
const setupBookmarks = (data) => {
    let favoritesHTML, bookmarksHTML = '';
    const bookmarkData = [];
    if (data && data.length) {
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const bookmarkId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000);
            const bookmark = doc.data();
            if (bookmark.favorite) {
                favoritesHTML += bookmarkHTML(bookmark, bookmarkId);
            } else {
                bookmarksHTML += bookmarkHTML(bookmark, bookmarkId);
            }
            bookmarkData.push({bookmark, bookmarkId});
        })
    }
    favoriteList.innerHTML = favoritesHTML;
    bookmarkList.innerHTML = bookmarksHTML;
    return bookmarkData;
}
```

Here is shortened version of the bookmarkHTML function, which simply adds the HTML to the favoritesHTML and bookmarksHTML variables in the previous function:

```
const bookmarkHTML = (bookmark, bookmarkId) => {
    let html = '';
    const li = `
        <li>
            <div class="row card-margin">
                <div class="col s12 m12 card-padding">
                    <div class="card-panel teal card-size">
                        <img src='${"https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=" + bookmark.url}' alt='icon' class='img-size'>
                        <a class='white-text' href='${bookmark.url}' target='_blank'>${bookmark.website}</a>
                        <button class='btn-flat btn-small right cross' id='${bookmarkId}'><i class='material-icons'>clear</i></button>
                        <button class='btn-flat waves-light btn-small right listener' id='${bookmarkId}'><i class='material-icons left'>compare_arrows</i>switch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    `;
    html += li;
    return html;
}
```

What could be causing this 'undefined' to appear in the HTML of my website upon being loaded up?

Comment: Your `bookmarkHTML` is defined as an empty string, it doesn't change till the point you use it as a function `bookmarkHTML(bookmark...` maybe that's what causing it?

Comment: @pritam That is exactly what was causing it. Thanks!